# Get diagonal values of spiral matrix

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I have a n*n spiral matrix.

> if N = 4
>
> then matrix :
>
> ```
>  7  8  9 10   
>  6  1  2 11  
>  5  4  3 12   
> 16 15 14 13
> ```
>
> if N = 3
>
> ```
>  7 8 9
>  6 1 2
>  5 4 3
> ```

I want to get the diagonal values of this spiral matrix.

In the `n=4` case diagonal values would be 7,1,3,13,10,2,4,16

I can do this by storing this matrix in array and traversing for each diagonal value.
Is there any better way to get these values.

Comment: How are you storing your matrix if not in an array? Could you post your code so far?

Comment: right now i am storing in array but it can be any other data type.

Comment: @pgmann See [Ulam spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral). The OP is asking if the numbers on the diagonal can be identified without storing the numbers in the matrix in a spiral fashion or *without storing anywhere at all*.

Comment: are you only interested in the corner-to-corner diagonals? the Ulam spiral shows significantly greater strings of primes along other diagonals. I wonder if there's a function for determining those maximums...

Comment: @JeffPuckettII yes

Comment: Do you need the elements in the order they appear along the diagonal?

Comment: @WilliamKunkel it can be in any order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the numbers on the main diagonal, we can notice that the values are

```
1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 + 4 = 7
1 + 2 + 4 + 6 = 13
```

So the general formula is 1 + (sum i = 0 to k of 2*i) for k = 0, 1, 2, ...
Simplifying this, we get k^2 + k + 1 for k = 0, 1, 2, ...

In PHP, we can generate these via something like this:

```
function mainDiagonal($n) {
    $values = array();

    for ($k = 0; $k < $n; $k++) {
        $values[] = $k*$k + $k + 1;
    }

    return $values;
}
```

To get the numbers on the antidiagonal for even N we see:

```
2 = 2
2 + 2 = 4
2 + 2 + 6 = 10
2 + 2 + 6 + 6 = 16
```

If we continue this pattern for larger matrices we see the general formula is

sum i = 0 to k of floor(i/2)*4 + 2 for k = 0, 1, 2, ...

Similarly for odd N we find the formula is

1 + (sum i = 0 to k of ceil(i/2)*4) for k = 0, 1, 2, ...

In PHP, we can generate these via something like this:

```
function antiDiagonal($n) {
    $values = array();

    if ($n % 2 == 0) {
        for ($k = 0; $k < $n; $k++) {
            $accum = 0;

            for ($j = 0; $j <= $k; $j++) {
                $accum += floor($j/2)*4 + 2;
            }

            $values[] = $accum;
        }
    } else {
        for ($k = 0; $k < $n; $k++) {
            $accum = 1;

            for ($j = 0; $j <= $k; $j++) {
                $accum += ceil($j/2)*4;
            }

            $values[] = $accum;
        }
    }

    return $values;
}
```

Notice that the maximum value of k is one less than the dimension of the matrix.

Combining these functions, we obtain:

```
array_unique(array_merge(mainDiagonal($n), antiDiagonal($n)))
```

Comment: In case of n = 3 (or any odd value of N), anti diagonal values are wrong

Comment: I have added a spiral matrix for n = 3 in question

Comment: Whoops, should be fixed now.

Comment: I think you've got a brilliant approach, but the function currently only returns one diagonal.

Comment: I'm adding the other as we speak.

Comment: nice, so how about adding `print_r(array_unique(array_merge(mainDiagonal($n),antiDiagonal($n))));`

Comment: Thanks @WilliamKunkel using this anti and main diagonal approach i wrote  a code which i think would be best. thank you so much again for helping me

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be divided into 4 parts: Find the numbers along the diagonal spoke in each quadrant. There are four quadrants, so we have four spokes:

1. Northwest (NW) spoke
2. Northeast (NE) spoke
3. Southwest (SW) spoke
4. Southeast (SE) spoke

For example, in your illustration of Ulam spiral, when N is even.

1. NW spoke have 1, 7, ...
2. NE spoke have 2, 10, ...
3. SW spoke have 4, 16, ...
4. SE spoke have 3, 13, ...

The problem is further subdivided into two cases:

1. N is even.
2. N is odd.

#### Case 1: N is even

Here are the formulas for each spoke:

```
NW spoke: f(n) = 4*n*n + 2*n + 1
NE spoke: g(n) = 4*n*n + 4n + 2
SW spoke: h(n) = 4*n*n + 8*n + 4
SE spoke: i(n) = 4*n*n + 6*n + 3
```

where n = 0, 1, 2, ...

For 4x4 matrix, compute the following set:

```
{f(0), f(1), g(0), g(1), h(0), h(1), i(0), i(1)}
```

It yields the diagonal values:

```
{1, 7, 2, 10, 4, 16, 3, 13}
```

In general, for an NxN matrix, when N is even, compute the following set to get the diagonal values:

```
{ f(0), ..., f(N/2 - 1),
  g(0), ..., g(N/2 - 1),
  h(0), ..., h(N/2 - 1),
  i(0), ..., i(N/2 - 1) }
```

#### Case 2: N is odd

In your illustration of Ulam spiral, when N is odd, the formulas for each spoke are:

```
NW spoke: f(n) = 4*n*n + 2*n + 1
NE spoke: g(n) = 4*n*n + 4*n + 1
SW spoke: h(n) = 4*n*n + 1
SE spoke: i(n) = 4*n*n - 2*n + 1
```

where n = 0, 1, 2, ...

Note that f(0) = g(0) = h(0) = i(0) = 1.

For 3x3, compute the following set:

```
{f(0), f(1), g(1), h(1), i(1)}
```

It yields the following diagonal values:

```
{1, 7, 9, 5, 3}.
```

In general, for an NxN matrix, when N is odd, compute the following set to get the diagonal values:

```
{ f(0), ..., f((N - 1)/2,
  g(0), ..., g((N - 1)/2),
  h(0), ..., h((N - 1)/2),
  i(0), ..., i((N - 1)/2) }
```

#### PHP Code

Finally, here is a PHP program that demonstrates what I have discussed above.

```
<?php
function ulam_diag($N)
{
    $result = array();

    if ($N % 2 == 0) {
        for ($n = 0; $n < $N / 2; $n++) {
            $result[] = 4*$n*$n + 2*$n + 1;
            $result[] = 4*$n*$n + 4*$n + 2;
            $result[] = 4*$n*$n + 8*$n + 4;
            $result[] = 4*$n*$n + 6*$n + 3;
        }
    } else {
        $result[] = 1;
        for ($n = 1; $n <= ($N - 1) / 2; $n++) {
            $result[] = 4*$n*$n + 2*$n + 1;
            $result[] = 4*$n*$n + 4*$n + 1;
            $result[] = 4*$n*$n + 1;
            $result[] = 4*$n*$n - 2*$n + 1;         
        }
    }

    sort($result);
    return $result;
}

print_r(ulam_diag(4));
print_r(ulam_diag(3));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 13
    [7] => 16
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 9
)
```

Here is the code one Ideone: http://ideone.com/F9jaC0

In case you are wondering how I arrived at the formulas, there are well established results for the four spokes of Ulam spiral. Here are the references:

1. https://oeis.org/A054569 (NW spoke in your illustration)
2. https://oeis.org/A016754 (NE spoke in your illustration)
3. https://oeis.org/A053755 (SW spoke in your illustration)
4. https://oeis.org/A054554 (SE spoke in your illustration)

The Ulam spirals in your illustrations are oriented differently from the popular representation of Ulam spirals, so I took these well known results and adjusted the offset of n for each formula, so that it works with your Ulam spiral. These adjustments are left as exercises to the reader. ;-)

Comment: For N = 3, "1"  would be placed in which spoke?

Comment: "1" is part of all the spokes. That's why `f(0) = g(0) = h(0) = i(0) = 1`. Therefore, we just output `1` as one of the diagonal values always (it's hard-coded in the PHP code) and then compute f(n), g(n), h(n), i(n) for integers n = 1, 2, ...

Answer (score 0):

Well for each row in a matrix we have two diagonal values. To obtain these two values i used two position(x1,y1) and (x2,y2) for main and anti diagonals.

Well I wrote this code:

```
<?php
    function getSpiralDiagonal($spiralArr,$N){
        $diagonalValueCount = $N*2;
        $xIndexMainDiagonal = 0;
        $yIndexMainDiagonal = 0;
        $xIndexAntiDiagonal = 0;
        $yIndexAntiDiagonal = $N-1;
        while($diagonalValueCount > 0){
            //checking for same position
            if($yIndexMainDiagonal == $yIndexAntiDiagonal){
                echo $spiralArr[$xIndexMainDiagonal][$yIndexMainDiagonal].'<br>';
            }else{
                echo $spiralArr[$xIndexMainDiagonal][$yIndexMainDiagonal].'<br>';
                echo $spiralArr[$xIndexAntiDiagonal][$yIndexAntiDiagonal].'<br>';
            }

            $xIndexMainDiagonal++;
            $yIndexMainDiagonal++;
            $xIndexAntiDiagonal++;
            $yIndexAntiDiagonal--;
            $diagonalValueCount -= 2;
        }
    }

    $spiralArr = array(array('7','8','9'),array('6','1','2'),array('5','4','3'));
    getSpiralDiagonal($spiralArr,3);
?>
```